# MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager with each HttpClient needing unique cookies and host

Tags: java, httpclient

I've been reading the Apache javadocs and have concluded that the correct way to handle a heavily multithreaded application which involves HttpClient is to use a static singleton `MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager` with a global HttpClient, with each thread having its instance of HttpState for its cookies and HostConfiguration. Is this correct? Obviously I want to avoid each thread interfering with the others' states.

Also, one of the problems I've been noticing is that when these threads end the socket associated with the HttpClient remains (checking /proc/###/fd), even after `RequestMethod.releaseConnection()` is called in the finally block. This is a problem as the default limit for fd is 1024 and this will be breached after a few days. What's the best way to kill with these left over sockets?

The only applicable method I can see for killing these sockets is `MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.closeIdleConnections(timeout)`- is this correct?

This means I'm going to have to either instantiate another thread to periodically call this method, or just call it every time the threads are killed manually, which seems quite clunky. Any advice?

Thanks a lot